# Excel: Counting cells with colour and text: Concatenating Countif and Countcolour VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel with coloured type of events and who organises them.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSigb.png)

I have created a macro for Countcolour which works well:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

And then with countif I've covered the events organised by each organiser.

How can I get events organised per team AND per colour?

I have tried countifs, sum, contatenated ifs and sumproducts but seem to not get a good outcome.

Thank you,

Raquel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use range:

```
rng = Range("e10:e104").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(0, -3)
```

as an argument in your `CountCcolor` function and you will get the counts for the team ORG1. The others by analogy.